# In Python, how can I calculate correlation and statistical significance between two arrays of data?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, correlation

I have sets of data with two equally long arrays of data, or I can make an array of two-item entries, and I would like to calculate the correlation and statistical significance represented by the data (which may be tightly correlated, or may have no statistically significant correlation).

I am programming in Python and have scipy and numpy installed. I looked and found [Calculating Pearson correlation and significance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python), but that seems to want the data to be manipulated so it falls into a specified range.

What is the proper way to, I assume, ask scipy or numpy to give me the correlation and statistical significance of two arrays?

Comment: Why do you think that `scipy.stats.pearsonr` wants the data to be manipulated so it falls into a specified range?

Comment: The _correlation coefficient_ falls between -1 and +1. That's the output, not the input.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to calculate the Pearson Correlation Coefficient, then `scipy.stats.pearsonr` is the way to go; although, the significance is only meaningful for larger data sets. This function does not require the data to be manipulated to fall into a specified range. The value for the correlation falls in the interval `[-1,1]`, perhaps that was the confusion?

If the significance is not terribly important, you can use `numpy.corrcoef()`.

The Mahalanobis distance does take into account the correlation between two arrays, but it provides a distance measure, not a correlation. (Mathematically, the Mahalanobis distance is not a true distance function; nevertheless, it can be used as such in certain contexts to great advantage.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Mahalanobis distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html) between these two arrays, which takes into account the correlation between them.

The function is in the scipy package: `scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis`

There's a nice example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935271/one-dimensional-mahalanobis-distance-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

**scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean()**

This gives euclidean distance between 2 points, 2 np arrays, 2 lists, etc

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as spsd
spsd.euclidean(nparray1, nparray2)
```

You can find more info here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html